# I wanted to know how to call a function from C++ executable using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I wanted to know how to call a function from C++ executable using NSIS.

I am using the below method but it is not calling the function.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  File E:\TestNullSoft\Test1.exe
  File E:\TestNullSoft\Test2.dll

System::Call 'KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory(w "$INSTDIR")'

Pop $1 ;
${If} $0 = 0
    MessageBox MB_OK "Function is NOT CALLED" IDOK
    
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

AddDllDirectory function is declared in the C++ project like as shown below:

Comment: Why do you have `Pop $1`? You should not copy random code you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call functions in .EXE files, only .DLL files.

Specifically, `System::Call` will call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` and `LoadLibrary` cannot load a .EXE.

Comment: so, there is no way to call the functions in the executable. And need a suggestion: We need to call several functions from the executalbes.(.exes) to display different notification dialogs. So, is it better way to move to other windows installer instead of NSIS? Please suggest..

Comment: It is impossible to call a function inside a .exe from another process on Windows, does not matter which installer technology you use.

Comment: Thank you for the information. We are planning to continue with NULLSOFT installer. If required to calls the .exe, we are calling  Exec "" "$INSTDIR\Test.exe". If there is a need to call the function in the executable, then writing the wrapper to that function in the .DLL and exporting it.